# Sum up Kills of Player List

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Basically I have a List of Players:

```
    final List<String> members = getClanMembers(clan);
```

Each of the Player has a number of **KILLS**.

I want to sum that up and get the **TOTAL KILLS** of all players.

This is what I am doing now:

```
    Integer kills = 0;
    for (final String plr : members) {
        try {
            final PreparedStatement sel = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT kills FROM Stats WHERE player=?");
            sel.setString(1, plr);
            final ResultSet rs = sel.executeQuery();
            kills += rs.getRow() != 0 ? rs.getInt("kills") : 0;
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However, I think this code is not efficient and I know that you can create variables in MySQL to do that better. (Bad stuff: try catch inside a for-loop, doing too many queries at once)

Could someone give me some tips?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I ONLY want to sum up the Kills of the Players **in the ArrayList**, not all Players in the Table.

Comment: Write an appropriate query that does such aggregation.

Comment: ... and use `IN` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SUM()` function in conjunction with a `WHERE player IN ...` clause that restricts the summing to only those records in the specified clan.

```
SELECT SUM(kills) FROM Stats WHERE player IN (?, ?, ?)
```

Note: You need to insert the correct number of '?' for the number of players in your array, then set those parameters to the player names from your array.

```
Integer kills = 0;
if(members.size() > 0) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT SUM(kills) FROM Stats WHERE player in (?");
    for(int index = 1; index < members.size(); index++) {
        sql.append(",?");
    }
    sql.append(")");
    try {
        final PreparedStatement sel = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        for (int index = 0; index < members.size(); index++) {
            sel.setString(index + 1, members.get(index));
        }
        final ResultSet rs = sel.executeQuery();
        kills = rs.getRow() != 0 ? rs.getInt(1) : 0;
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use MySQL to perform the entire [SUM()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.htmll#function_sum) in a single row and column with

```
SELECT SUM(kills) FROM Stats
```

Then `rs.getInt(1)` will return the total across all players.

**Edit**

Convert the `members` list into a comma separated list of player_ids, and add a "WHERE player IN" clause to the query above and you'll get the totals only for those players.